# Weird error with pool module and beautiful soup: Invalid URL 'h'

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a very large website with Beautiful Soup for a project and want to use the Pool module to speed it up. I am getting a weird error where it is not correctly reading the list of URL's, as far as I can tell it is just grabbing the first 'h'.

The entire code works perfectly if I do not use pool. The list of URL's is read properly. I am not sure if there is something weird about how you have to prepare the URL's when calling `p.map(scrapeClauses, links)` because if I simply call `scrapeClauses(links)` everything works.

Here is my main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    links = list()
    og = 'https://www.lawinsider.com'
    halflink = '/clause/limitation-of-liability'
    link = og + halflink
    links.append(link)
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        try:
            nextLink = generateNextLink(link)        
            links.append(nextLink)
            link = nextLink
            i += 1
        except:
            print('Only ', i, 'links found')
            i = 50
    start_time = time.time()
    print(links[0])
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(scrapeClauses, links)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    #scrapeClauses(links)
```

and here is `scrapeClauses()`:

```
def scrapeClauses(links):
    #header to avoid site detecting scraper
    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
    headers.update({
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
    })
    #list of clauses
    allText = []
    number = 0
    for line in links:
        page_link = line
        print(page_link)
        page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
        html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
        assignments = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ ='snippet-content')
        for i in range(len(assignments)):
            assignments[i] = assignments[i].get_text()
            #option to remove te assignment that precedes each clause
            #assignments[i] = assignments[i].replace('Assignment.','',1)
            allText.append(assignments[i])
            #change the index of the name of the word doc
            name = 'limitationOfLiability' + str(number) + '.docx'
            #some clauses have special characters tat produce an error
            try:
                document = Document()
                stuff = assignments[i]
                document.add_paragraph(stuff)
                document.save(name)
                number += 1
            except:
                continue
```

I did not include `generateNextLink()` to save space and because I am pretty sure the error is not in there but if someone thinks it is I will provide it.

As you can see I 'print(page_link) in `scrapeClauses`. If I am not using pool, it will print all the normal links. But if I use pool, a bunch of h's print out line after line. I then get and error that h is not a valid URL. I will show the error code below.

```
https://www.lawinsider.com/clause/limitation-of-liability
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
h
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiproce
ssing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiproce
ssing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\Web Scraping\assignmentBSScraper.py", line 20, in scrape
Clauses
    page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\wquinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ges\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps
you meant http://h?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `p.map` get an list. Each such element will be sent to a function. So you function got a `string` and not a `list of string` as you expect.

The minimal example is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(str_list):
  for x in str_list:
    print ('hello {}'.format(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  str_list = ['111', '2', '33']
  p = Pool(5)
  p.map(f, str_list)
  p.terminate()
  p.join()
```

Output is:

```
hello 1
hello 1
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 3
```